Why are my django-allauth socialaccount template tags empty?
I am using Django 5.0.6 with django-allauth 0.63.3. I followed the allauth quick start guide to configure my settings.py and used pip install "django-allauth[socialaccount]" , and was able to setup google and github SSO providers through settings.py file.
settings.py
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'github': {...},
    'google': {...},
}

I confirmed they both show up and links work in "/accounts/login" endpoint from allauth. However, when making a custom login form, the template tags are empty allauth template reference.
login.html
{% load socialaccount %}

{% get_providers as socialaccount_providers %}

<div>{{socialaccount_providers}}</div>

I have also tried configuring the providers through the django admin console, but that did not solve the issue. It just made the login page have conflicting duplicate links. I have also reinstalled the package through pip. I was able to debug the output in the view function and verify that get_providers returns the correct response here.
views.py
def user_login(request):
  from allauth.socialaccount.templatetags.socialaccount import get_providers
  res = get_providers({"request": request})
  return HttpResponse(res)


it looks like you want to use a custom login.html template rather than the alluth own. So two thing could be involved. either you override the allauth module views to point to your custom login.html. or your modify the allauth module template to your taste.
